# C# add minutes to timer (WPF/XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, timer

Need some help. Took a timer from one of the other site users, work wonderful, but I need to add buttons (methods) to increase time when timer is on. Tried this, but it doesn't work. When program is working and I press the buttons time seems to be added but in the same millisecond it returns to its place. And even if you increase the time before the start of the timer at startup, it is reset. Please help

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //for timer
    private DateTime _startCountdown; // time start
    private TimeSpan _startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10); // start time until the end of the timer 
    private TimeSpan _timeToEnd; // time to stop. Changes when timer is on
    private TimeSpan _interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15); // interval 
    private DateTime _pauseTime;

    //for additional time 
    private TimeSpan _plusOneMinute = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    private TimeSpan _plusTwoMinutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
    private DispatcherTimer _timer;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _timer.Interval = _interval;
        _timer.Tick += delegate
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var elapsed = now.Subtract(_startCountdown);
            TimeToEnd = _startTimeSpan.Subtract(elapsed);
        };
        StopTimer();

        releaseButton.IsEnabled = false;
        pauseButton.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    //methods for work with timer(buttons)
    public TimeSpan TimeToEnd
    {
        get
        {
            return _timeToEnd;
        }

        set
        {
            _timeToEnd = value;
            if (value.TotalMilliseconds <= 0)
            {
                StopTimer();
                MessageBox.Show(winnerName, "we have a winner!");
                lotesView.Clear();
                lotes.Clear();
            }

            OnPropertyChanged("StringCountdown");
        }
    }

    public string StringCountdown
    {
        get
        {
            var frmt = TimeToEnd.Minutes < 1 ? "ss\\.ff" : "mm\\:ss";
            return _timeToEnd.ToString(frmt);
        }
    }

    public bool TimerIsEnabled
    {
        get { return _timer.IsEnabled; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    private void StopTimer()
    {
        if (TimerIsEnabled)
            _timer.Stop();
        TimeToEnd = _startTimeSpan;
    }

    private void PlusOneMinute()//doesn't work
    {
        TimeToEnd = TimeToEnd + _plusOneMinute;
    }

    private void PlusTwoMinutes()//doesn't work
    {
        TimeToEnd = TimeToEnd + _plusTwoMinutes;
    }

    private void StartTimer(DateTime sDate)
    {
        _startCountdown = sDate;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void PauseTimer()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _pauseTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private void ReleaseTimer()
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var elapsed = now.Subtract(_pauseTime);
        _startCountdown = _startCountdown.Add(elapsed);
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StartTimer(DateTime.Now);
        pauseButton.IsEnabled = true;
        startButton.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StopTimer();
        pauseButton.IsEnabled = false;
        releaseButton.IsEnabled = false;
        startButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PauseTimer();
        pauseButton.IsEnabled = false;
        releaseButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReleaseTimer();
        releaseButton.IsEnabled = false;
        pauseButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    private void Button_Click_PlusOne(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlusOneMinute();
    }

    private void Button_Click_PlusTwo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlusTwoMinutes();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working since the part that calculating the time to end is your .Thick implementation

```
_timer.Tick += delegate
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var elapsed = now.Subtract(_startCountdown);
        TimeToEnd = _startTimeSpan.Subtract(elapsed);
    };
```

when you change the TimeToEnd var it changes again on the next tick event.
you can change the addtion of timeing like this:

```
private void PlusOneMinute()//doesn't work
{
    _startCountdown += _plusOneMinute;
}

 private void PlusTwoMinutes()//doesn't work
{
    TimeToEnd += _plusTwoMinutes;
}
```

this way you will change the time remains on the Tick event and it should work